# How to allow seperate form to use list of objects on another?

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, generic-list

I have a list of objects on my main form - `GUI` - and while I can access that list using a `foreach` loop for example `foreach (Employee emp in employees)`
this allows me to access the employees within the list.

On the other form I have some code that requires it to access the list of employees.

So far I have tried to copy the `private List<Employee> employees;`
but it gives me a null reference exception obviously meaning that there's nothing in the list that has been copied over.

I'll provide a view of my code so you can have something to base your solution off:

**Code**
Main form

```
private List<Employee> employees;
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
employees = new List<Employee>();
}
Employee e1 = new Employee(MemberJob.Employee, "Name", MemberSkills.CPlus);
```

Added this bit of code in case I need to send some variables into the form

```
private void btnAddJob_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
CreateAJob newForm2 = new CreateAJob();
newForm2.ShowDialog();
}
```

---

**Additional Form code **

```
private string _jobName = "";
private string _jobDifficulty = "";
private string _skillRequired = "";
private int _shiftsLeft = 0;
private List<Employee> employees; // tried to copy this over but there's nothing in it
public CreateAJob()
{
InitializeComponent();
}
public CreateAJob(string _jobName, string _skillRequired, int _shiftsLeft)
{
this._jobName = JobName;
this._skillRequired = SkillRequired;
this._shiftsLeft = ShiftsLeft;
}
private void Distribute(string _jobName, int _shiftsLeft, string _skillsRequired)
{
foreach (Employee emp in employees)
{
while (emp.Busy == true)
{
if (emp.Busy == false && emp.Skills.ToString() == _skillRequired)
{
emp.EmployeeWorkload = _jobName;
emp.ShiftsLeft = _shiftsLeft;
}
... additional code to finish method
```

Comment: You seem to think that creating a NEW list of Employees with the same name of another list of employees involves some kind of copy. That's not true. You should pass the first list to the second form and assign the variable declared inside the CreateAJob form to the same instance of the Main form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another constructor and pass the `Employee` list like this

**CreateAJob form:**

```
internal CreateAJob(List<Employee> employees)
    : this() // Make sure the normal constructor is executed
{
    this.employees = employees;
}
```

**Main form:**

```
private void btnAddJob_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateAJob newForm2 = new CreateAJob(employees);
    newForm2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: it says "Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type ``List<Employee>` is less accessible than method `CreateAJob.CreateAJob(List<Employee>)``

I am assuming this is because I have made something private but I do not want to make the list public

Comment: @DannyWatson Most probably your `Employee` class in `internal`. In such case you need to make the new constructor `internal` too, as in the updated answer.